# Python won't create / write to a file

Tags: python

I am new at python and learning the language. The following code should create a file in the running program directory and write to it but it doesn't do this at all in a .py file. If I put the same code in the IDLE shell it returns 17. No errors just doesn't create the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
with open("st.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Hi from Python!")
```

Thanks for the help
Mike

Comment: Try with a full qualified path instead of `"st.txt"`

Comment: ...and also check the current directory : `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Use `w+`, so the filw would also created if it does not exist `with open("st.txt", "w+") as f:`

Comment: @MDennis Just setting the mode to `'w'` is good enough to create the file.

Comment: Works for me, as is.

Comment: yeah, 'w' is enough.@pstatix

Comment: Thanks for the reply it turned out to be a permissions issue with the path. I also had to pass the r before the path in the open method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This code is flawless, no problem!**

I guess that in your REPL shell, the $PWD environment variable is set for somewhere, so your destination file is in some corner.

No exception thrown indicates that **no problem with access authority.**

**Maybe you can set some absolute path string, such as `~/st.txt`**

By the way, the successful invoke should return 15 instead of 17, totally count 15 chars.

Answer (score 0):

your code works well, st.txt will be touched at executing path.

other ways, your system account can't write in your execute path.

try in your $HOME path to execute your code, I think, It will work well